# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined (Giving props through link)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I can't retrieve the props gived on the Link attribute.

Here is the code of my ***Link class component*** :

```
export default class ChooseReserv extends Component {
    token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    state = {nb: 1, html : []};
    test = 0;

    componentDidMount = () =>  {
        axios.get('Parking', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token}}).then(
        res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.loadAllUsers(res.data);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    loadAllUsers = (data) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = (
            <div id={data[i].id}>
                {data[i].name}
                <button style={{marginLeft: "50px"}} type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><Link style={{color: "white"}} className="nav-link" to={{
                    pathname:'/myReserv', 
                    state: {
                        data: data[i]
                    }
                }}>Go</Link></button>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        )
        this.setState({ html: this.state.html.concat([value]) })
    }
}

    render() {
        var htmle = this.state.html;
        console.log("html" + htmle);
        if (this.props.connected == 'false') {
            return <Redirect to={'/'}/>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Réserver votre place de parking !</h1>
                <div className="auth-wrapper">
                    <div className="auth-inner">
                         {htmle}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to **retrieve the props in the Redirect page** like that :

```
export default class MyReserv extends Component {
    token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      
      componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data);
      }

      
    render() {
        if (this.props.connected == 'false') {
            return <Redirect to={'/'}/>;
        }
        return (
            <div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">
            <h2>Bienvenue .</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But React is giving me an error.. : **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"**

So how can i retrieve these data ? (im on **React-router v5.2**)

Comment: have you tried withRouter() higher order component in your component?

Comment: i have edited my post, this is an export default class, so i can't call withRouter() here no ? @Ehsan

Comment: it does not matter if it is export default or not. right your component like this below

Comment: so i put after the definition of my class the withRouter like that :  ```withRouter(MyReserv);```??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class MyReserv extends Component {
    token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      
      componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props.location.state.data);
      }

      
    render() {
        if (this.props.connected == 'false') {
            return <Redirect to={'/'}/>;
        }
        return (
            <div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">
            <h2>Bienvenue .</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyReserv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle methods should not be arrow functions.

try with:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('Parking', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token}}).then(
    res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.loadAllUsers(res.data);
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```